# Drupal 7: Can't Log Out: user/logout is a 404

Tags: php, apache, drupal, drupal-7

I have a drupal 7 site that I just moved to a new server. I'm logged in as admin, but when I click the logout button on the admin bar (I have admin module installed) or on the /user page, I get the following:

Page not found
The requested page "/user/logout" could not be found.

Looking in the apache logs reveals a 404 for /user/logout.
So, what's going on here? Flushing caches both locally and through the admin menu in drupal does nothing--I remain logged in, and the admin bar is still there, so I don't think it's a cache problem.

I'm fairly new to drupal, so please include extra detail in any responses. I won't necessarily know where to put php code if you just give me a block of it without context.

Comment: Are all other basic functions working (Clean URLs work, pages load, menus work, etc.)?

Comment: Yeah. This is the only thing that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be something fairly specific to my case. I had an  module installed which used the CAS module. It allowed authentication through a particular ldap server. (This module was built for all users of that particular ldap server, and isn't home-made or available on the drupal site) We'll call it foo_cas for expedience. When I moved to the new server, foo_cas was no longer required--besides that, foo_cas broke and no longer allowed me to login to the ldap server.  My new server did not have the php ldap plugin installed, and I suspect that that's why.

Anyway, after the move, I couldn't log in again to disable foo_cas (because of the above ldap problem), so I just deleted the folder sites/all/modules/foo_cas on the backend. This is what broke the logout url. I'm not sure what did it on the code level in foo_cas.
My solution in the end was to put the foo_cas folder back in the sites/all/modules directory, which made the module available again, but disabled. I then used the uninstall tab under modules in the UI to uninstall foo_cas.
I suspect foo_cas made a database change when it was installed that needed to be undone properly by uninstalling it. Now, /user/logout works again.